# How do I stop Word from adding a space when pasting after "]("?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

Sometimes, I use MS Word to draft content in Markdown, due to autosave and other helpful features.  The syntax for a link is to have the readable text in square brackets immediately followed by the URL in parentheses, like this: 
`[Super User](http://superuser.com)`.
Commonly, I copy the URL from a browser, and go to paste it into the draft.

If I paste in Notepad, or most places in the Word document, the first characters (http...) begin immediately where the cursor was when I hit paste.

However, if I'm in Word with the cursor immediately after a `](` sequence, Word **adds a space** before the URL, breaking the markdown link (depending on parser strictness).  It also does this if pasting text from elsewhere even in the same document, with no leading space.

How do I stop Word from doing this?

(Edition: Office 365 ProPlus, macros disabled).

---

Per comments from @fixit: After a paste in Word, I copied the )[ through the pasted content and pasted it in cell A1 of an Excel spreadsheet.  In A2, I put the formula `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)` ([equivalent](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/right-rightb-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f) to `substring(1)` in some other programming languages) and dragged that formula down several columns, with each row's A cell showing the same as the previous row minus the first character.

In the next column (B1) I used the formula `=CODE(A1)` which [shows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/code-function-c32b692b-2ed0-4a04-bdd9-75640144b928) the character code for the first character in the string.

Where that space character is first (A3), the code (B3) is 32.  As this is on a Windows machine, that's the [ANSI character set](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php), for which values 0-127 match [ASCII](http://ascii-table.com/ascii.php), and character 32 is a space.  Therefore, the character in question is a space, not some nonprintable character that Notepad ignores and Word shows as a space.   Additionally, if such a character were part of the copied string, it would show up when pasted after other characters, such as `(` when it is *not* immediately preceded by `]`.  However, in such cases, no space is added.

Comment: There's no reason why it should do that.  I'm wondering if, at some point, you did such a paste and Word is now auto-correcting it for you, or something similar.  Another thought, your URL copy action might be including some unexpected character.  Notepad doesn't deal with it because it's a non-print character, but Word displays it as a space.  It might be worth experimenting with how you select the string to copy.   e.g., start the selection past the first character, paste, and see if you still get the space.   (cont'd)

Comment: Also, copy the Word string with the extra space and put it into Excel.  Use Excel's text functions to determine exactly what character that space is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **Adjust sentence and word spacing automatically** setting is getting in the way of your desired behavior.

It's several layers deep within the `Options` menu structure.

`File` > `Options` > `Advanced` > `Cut, Copy and Paste` > `Smart Cut and Paste` > `Settings`. Clear the "Adjust sentence and word spacing automatically" option.

Comment: Any idea where that is in Microsoft Word Online (part of Office 365)?

Comment: @OlivierCailloux, I don't know. It's in the same place for me with "Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise". I don't know how Microsoft Word Online might differ.

Comment: Thanks. [This thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/no-options-in-word-online/50f9f761-199a-4d76-b4d8-4c178ad30f89) suggests that what I am looking for simply does not exist, unfortunately.

Comment: For Outlook 2016, this is at `File` > `Options` > `Mail` > `Spelling and Autocorrect...` > `Advanced` > `Cut, copy, and paste` > `Use smart cut and paste` (`Settings`) > `Adjust sentence and word spacing automatically`